# Telegram API - Delete unknown spam messages form spammer bots in Telegram Group

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I got some issues with spammer bots in my telegram group.

They forward some spyware (apk) contents from a channel which is not exists. and in shape of silent messages.

i made an Anti Spam bot (PHP) for such messages.it pretty works for other message , but when the Bad-Bots send such messages to group , i receive no update in my webhook script to check if is_bot or not....
i mean my anti spam bot cant see those message since it cant receive updates from (only)such messages  ... 
they're like ghosts....

BTW i implemented a temporary way to avoid them.
it kicks them when they coming to group and anyone who invites them.(still send those unknown spams upon entering group :D )
and it checks every message index and attempt to delete unknown ids from group. it does'nt work. i get this error when i try to delete that message by index id :

```
{
"ok":false,
"error_code":400,
"description":"Bad Request: message to delete not found"
}
```

how to recognize such messages in my group ?
is there any trick in Telegram API to prevent these messages ?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE (ANSWER):**

thanks to [@Pato05](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6529252/pato05) guidance . i like to share my search result.
i found this library to create UserBot with much more privileges than basic bot. just like normal user client.

https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto

Created a user with this lib and managed to get updates and control my group messages.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots can't see each other's message to avoid conflicts. They neither can't delete messages.
So, I suggest you creating an userbot and adding it to your group if you want to see and delete bot messages.